# Add block to specific node in drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-blocks

What is the best way to add a block with custom design to a specific node?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

step 1: Find out the node id or the url alias of the node.

step 2: Go to your block, in editing mode, scroll to the bottom of the page to the "Page specific visibility settings" section.

step 3: Select "Show on only the listed pages.", enter the node's url to the textbox below.

i.e. "node/16" (where 16 is the id of the node), or "content/sample-page" (where "sameple-page" is the node's url alias)

Comment: "Best" is a highly subjective question. Drupal Core's built in mechanism for this is a fine thing. More advanced use cases and site architectures might call for leveraging contrib modules like Panels or Context.